# Django - show all images assigned to the post

Tags: python, django

I am creating blog application and I would like to show all images which were uploaded to the single blog post.

Here are my Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

class PostImage(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postimages')
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')
```

Views.py

```
class PostGalleryView(DetailView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/gallery.html'
    context_object_name = 'photos'
```

In the template if I put there `{{ photos.postimages }}` then it shows on the page: blog.PostImage.None
even though that 2 images are uploaded to the particular blog post. `{{ photos.postimages.count }}` shows number 2. If I tried to loop through `photos.postimages` it throws an error: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable. Any idea how I can access the PostImage model in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using loop in your template with `all` like:

```
{% for photo in photos.postimages.all %}
    {{ photo.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it should be ```{{ photo.image }}```